# T-SQL query combination of available and selected in one row

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. One is the `library` table and the other one is the relational table (see below).  The `table1` lists all the possible mailing lists(or whatever), `table2` indicates the contact 'John' is listed in mailing list 1,3,4.
Is it possible to write a query to get all the available mailing list items and the selected items in one row?  Could you please help?

output in one row:

```
John,    A:1,  B:0,  C:1,  D:1,  E:0
Mary,    A:1,  B:0,  C:0,  D:0,  E:1
```

table1 (library table)

```
Id  Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

table2 (relation table)

```
contact Mail-id
John    1
John    3
John    4
Mary    1
Mary    5
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the desired output.

Comment: cross join John with table1 and left join table2, then PIVOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross join the distinct contact in table2 with table1 then left join the result with table2

If you want the mailing list in single column delimited with comma's then use `for xml path()` trick. Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT b.contact,
                a.NAME + CASE WHEN c.[Mail-id] IS NOT NULL THEN ':1' ELSE ':0' END AS aval_mailinglist
         FROM   tab1e1 a
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT contact
                            FROM   table2) b
                LEFT JOIN table2 c
                       ON a.Id = c.[Mail-id]
                       and b.contact=c.contact)
SELECT contact,
       stuff((SELECT ',' + aval_mailinglist
        FROM   cte b
        WHERE  a.contact = b.contact
        FOR xml path('')),1,1,'') Mailing_list
FROM   cte a 
group by contact
```

If you want the result in different columns then use `Pivot`

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(max)='',
        @sql  NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @cols += NAME
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT Quotename(Isnull(NAME, '')) + ',' NAME
       FROM   table1)a

SELECT @cols = LEFT(@cols, Len(@cols) - 1)

PRINT @cols

SET @sql=';WITH cte
     AS (SELECT b.contact,
                a.NAME + CASE WHEN c.[Mail-id] IS NOT NULL THEN '':1'' ELSE '':0'' END AS aval_mailinglist,
                a.name
         FROM   table1 a
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT contact
                            FROM   table2) b
                LEFT JOIN table2 c
                       ON a.Id = c.[Mail-id]
                       and b.contact=c.contact)

SELECT *
FROM   cte a 
pivot (max(aval_mailinglist) for name in ('
         + @cols + ') ) piv'

--print @sql
EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b44c86/1)

Comment: It seems not working correctly.  If I added more contact into the relation table. Then the query failed.  For example: If I added.

contact Mail-id
John    1
John    3
John    4
Mary   1
Mary   5

Comment: @GeorgeHuang - which output you need first query or second query

Comment: second query.. 
John,    A:1,  B:0,  C:1,  D:1,  E:0
Mary,    A:1,  B:0,  C:0,  D:0,  E:1
again, thank you very much for your help, hint or direction. :-)